# Going from a recursion formula to a recursion formula involving the logs only

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, recurrence-relations, computational-mathematics

I want to compute the terms $a_n$ from some recursion formula of the form:

$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^nb_ka_{n-k}$ with some initial condition $a_0$, and the $b_k$ are known.
Also, let's assume there is no closed form for $a_n$.

These terms grow very rapidly. Therefore I thought using a recursion formula involving the logs might be more tractable. However, I don't know if it is possible to go from this recursion formula involving $a_n$ and $b_n$ to another one involving $\log(a_n)$ and $\log(b_n)$ only. At first it seemed obvious to me, but I am somewhat doubting now.

The main problem I encounter there is that I get the log of a sum on the right-hand side, that I would like to express as a sum of the logs instead. Maybe some kind of good approximation is possible ?

Some context : this problem occurs in a physics problem, when computing recursively some partition function. I want to avoid overflow issues.

EDIT : adding some information:

If it is of any help, $b_k=(\frac{1}{1-e^{-k\beta}})^3$ where $\beta$ can be close to $0$ (so $b_k$ can possibly take very high values). The initial condition is $a_0=1$.

Comment: If $f_b(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}b_n x^n$ and $f_a(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n$, the recursion gives $a_n = -b_0 a_n + [x^n]f_a(x)f_b(x)$, so $f_a(x)$ is the solution of  simple differential equation and the order of growth of $a_n$ can be estimated with various techniques.

Comment: However, a precise answer requires a bit more knowledge on the $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ and $\{b_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ sequences. What do you actually know about them?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks for your input. I added some information at the bottom. I guess I could approximate $b_k$ for small $\beta$ (even if I'd rather not to... just to be sure of the relevance of my results)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$a_n
=\sum_{k=1}^nb_ka_{n-k}
$,
let
$A(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$
and
$B(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n
$.

Then,
in the usual manner,

$\begin{array}\\
A(x)B(x)
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_j x^j\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_i  b_j x^{i+j}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_i  b_{n-i} x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{n-i}  b_{i} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{n-i}  b_{i} \\
&=a_0b_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\left(a_nb_0+\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n-i}  b_{i}\right)\\
&=a_0b_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^na_nb_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n-i}  b_{i}\\
&=a_0b_0+b_0\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^na_n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n-i}  b_{i}\\
&=a_0b_0+b_0(A(x)-a_0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^n a_{n}\\
&=a_0b_0+b_0(A(x)-a_0)+(A(x)-a_0)\\
&=A(x)-a_0\\
\text{so}\\
a_0
&=A(x)-A(x)B(x)\\
&=A(x)(1-B(x))\\
\text{or}\\
A(x)
&=\dfrac{1}{1-B(x)}\\
\end{array}
$

If you can write
$1-B(x)
=\prod_{k=1}^m (c_k-x)
$,
you can get an estimate
for the growth of
the $a_n$
in terms of
the largest of the
$(1/c_k)^n$.

If $B(x)$ is a power series
rather than a polynomial,
it is harder.

Comment: In the current framework, it is reasonable to approximate $B(x)$ with $\frac{1}{1-x}+(b_1-1)x$. In such a case, the magnitude of $a_n$ (or $\log a_n$) is easy to compute and just depends on $b_1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio This would be achieved by comparing the series expansion at $x=0$ of the RHS right ? Or at b=+inf ?

Comment: @Evariste: it is a bit of both. If we approximate $B(x)$ in such a way, it is reasonable to expect that the closest zero to the origin of $B(x)-1$ is not changed by much, so neither it is the behaviour of $a_n$ that follows from $$A(x)=\frac{1}{1-B(x)}$$

Comment: @JackD'aurizio I don't get how I can infer the behaviour of a single $ a_n $ from that of the sum... The first term of the series expansion seems to be $-\frac {1}{b_1x}$. And now what ? I can't derive n times and evaluate at $0$ since it diverges

Comment: @Evariste: study the case $$ A(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n x^n = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1-x}-cx} $$ through partial fraction decomposition. Then approximate $1-B(x)$ with $1-\frac{1}{1-x}-cx$. That was my suggestion.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That's what I did (except for the decomposition). Now that I have decomposed the RHS I still don't see what it has to do with a single $ a_n$.

Comment: @Evariste: if $A(x)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{K}}$, what is $a_n$? I guess it is $\frac{1}{K^n}$...

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Finally got it... Thanks for your boundless patience.